# Can a DataTemplate be reused by binding it to different properties with the same data type?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datatemplate, reusability

I use a DataGrid with several columns of the same data type. I want to use a DataGridTemplateColumn for the columns and define a DataTemplate for the CellTemplate and one for the CellEditingTemplate.

Is it possible to bind the text of the DataTemplates to the respective source property?

ViewModel:

```
class Item : Notifier 
{
    private String name;
    public String Name 
    {
        get { return this.name; }
        set
        {
            this.name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    private String comment = String.Empty;
    public String Comment 
    {
        get { return this.comment; }
                
        set
        {
            this.comment = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Comment");
        }
    }
}

class MainWindowsViewModel : Notifier
{
    private List<Item> data = new List<Item>();
    public List<Item> Data { get { return this.data; } }
```

View:

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <viewmodel:MainWindowsViewModel x:Key="vm"/>

    <!-- readonly template -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="dt">
        <TextBlock Background="AliceBlue" Margin="5"
            Text="{Binding ???}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
        
    <!-- editing template -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="edt">
        <TextBox Background="LightCoral" Margin="10"
            Text="{Binding ???}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
    
<Grid>
    <DataGrid 
      DataContext="{StaticResource vm}"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"
      HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
      Margin="10,10,10,10" 
      VerticalAlignment="Top" 
      >
      <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn
                Header="Name"
                CellTemplate="{StaticResource dt}"
                CellEditingTemplate="{StaticResource edt}"
            />

            <DataGridTemplateColumn
              Header="Comment"
              CellTemplate="{StaticResource dt}"
              CellEditingTemplate="{StaticResource edt}"
            />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DataContext` of the `DataTemplate` is *always* an instance of the templated data type.

It really helps to set the `DataTemplate.DataType` property as this will enable code suggestions by the designer.

In your case, the `DataContext` of the templates is an `Item` instance:

```xml
<Window.Resources>

  <!-- readonly template -->
  <DataTemplate x:Key="dt" 
                DataType="Item">
    <StackPanel>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Comment}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

And avoid string literals whenever possible:

```
OnPropertyChanged("Comment");
```

should become

```
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.Comment));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I may not have understood your concept, because I am wondering what the advantage of a template is in this solution.

Comment: I was just modifying your posted code. You were asking how to define the data binding inside the DataTemplate.  I just added example bindings that use the current DataContext as binding source.  I also gave a brief explanation about the concept. If your question was if you can define a binding so that it can be used with any property, then based on this answer the conclusion is no. A Binding must consist of a source and a path. However, if the only cell content is a TextBlcok than simply define a DataGridTextColumn instead of a DataGridTemplateColumn.

Comment: *"I am wondering what the advantage of a template is in this solution"* - It allows you to customize the visual appearance of a DataGrid column for cases where the cell content is more complex than a simple text representation. The DataTemplate could contain a custom control or UserControl. Whatever it requires to design the cell.

Comment: Maybe you could clarify your question. I understood that you want to reuse the same DataTemplate for different columns? In other words, you don't know how to bind to the row item from within the DataTemplate or how data binding works (because that's the only context I can make sense of the question).

Comment: Yes, you're right, I should have explained it better. 

Your first comment "If your question was if you can define a binding so that it can be used with any property, then based on this answer the conclusion is no" is the answer to my question (where any property is limited to the same datatype in m,y question).

"I am wondering what the advantage of a template is in this solution": I think it's more of an organisational or methodological advantage, as I can also achieve the goal directly on the DataGridColumn. In any case, I have to define the column for each source property.

Comment: *"I think it's more of an organisational or methodological advantage, as I can also achieve the goal directly on the DataGridColumn"* - It's not an organizational nor a methodological advantage. A `DataTemplate` always defines how a data model (the type that the `DataTemplate` targets) is presented/rendered. `DataGrid` is an `ItemsControl` like the `ListBox` or `Combobox` for example. You bind data items to the `ItemsSource`. In the case of the `DataGrid` each item makes a row. But the `ItemsControl` does not know how to display the data item.

Comment: By default, it will use a `TextBlock` and will call the `object.ToString` method on the data item. In the case of `DataGrid` (if autogenerate columns is enabled) it will map each property to a column and create a `DataGridTextColumn` to show the data value. This is sufficient for most cases. However, if you don't want to display all properties or need an advanced layout presentation you can disable auto column generation and define columns explicitly. But how to tell the `ItemsControl` (e.g., `DataGrid`) how to present the data? --> `DataTemplate`.

Comment: Again, the row item is the data model, in your case of type `Item`. That's why the `DataTemplate.DataType` is set to `Item` in the above example. If you want a simple text presentation of the column value, simply define a `DataGridTextColumn` and set the Header property to the property of the data item it should display. The `DataGridTextColumn` will implicitly generate a `TextBlock` for the default cell template and a `TextBox` for the cell editing template.

Comment: If you want more control, you use `DataGridTemplateColumn` instead as this allows you to define your own presentation by providing a `DataTemplate` for normal display mode and/or an additional `DataTemplate` for the cell editing mode. The `DataTemplate` here serves the same purpose as it does for the `ListBox.ItemTemplate` (or `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` in general). The `DataTemplate` tells every control that can display data  (e.g., `ItemsControl` and subclasses, `ContentControl`), how the data has to be presented.

Comment: If you don't want to explicitly define each column, you can set `DataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns` to `true` (is already the default). If you need to define the columns explicitly but only want simple text representation, then use the `DataGridTextColumn` as this eliminates the need to define cell templates.

Comment: Only if you need to display more than a simple text representation or want to customize the appearance of the cell when in edit mode then use the `DataGridTemplateColumn`.  In this case you would have to explicitly provide the source path to the property of the row data item which requires you to define a dedicated `DataTemplate` for each column. Most common use cases don't require every column to be of type `DataGridTemplateColumn`. Most columns are of typ `DataGridTextColumn`. I guess most scenarios don't require explicit column definitions at all and auto column generation is sufficient.

Comment: [Microsoft learn: Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)